# If else statements inside jsp

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I have a following problem - if else statements do not work in JSP, and to be honest I have no idea why. Basically I try to change the `placeName` depending on what number is stored in a string called place. After printing the values in the browser I can see the value is not changed. I am sure it is something simple but... Maybe some one had similar problem before?

```
<%
//requests the strings sent by previous page
String year = request.getParameter("year");
String place = request.getParameter("place");
out.print(year);
out.print(place);

String year2 = request.getParameter("year2");
String place2 = request.getParameter("place2");
//out.print(year2);
//out.print(place2);

if (place == "1")
{
placeName = "Belmullet";
}
else if (place == "2")
{
placeName = "Birr";
}
...more statements here...
else if (place == "15")
{
placeName = "Shannon airport";
};
%>
```

Comment: You should use `.equals()` when comparing strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: For people who answered. Perhaps you want to explain a little but about the differences between `==` and `.equals()`

Comment: Remember that everything in java is a pointer, so when you use the == operator as found in c++, you are comparing the address.  Not the value stored.

Comment: Many thanks - it worked, I actually used that method before... The reason I did not think about it was that very similar code was used in Java Script - and it worked, so I thought it is something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the if condition:

```
if (place == "1") {

}
```

by

```
if ("1".equals(place)) {

}
```

and the same way for the other if conditions.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) may helps you to learn the difference between `==` and `equals()`.

Comment: Many thanks - it worked, I actually used that method before... The reason I did not think about it was that very similar code was used in Java Script - and it worked, so I thought it is something else

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're comparing Strings using ==. Instead, use the `.equals()` method.

The == operator tests to see if two object references refer to the exact same instance of an object.

The .equals() tests to see if the two objects being compared to each other are equivalent.

Comment: If `place` is `null`, this throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: if `place` is null in his original code, it throws a `NullPointerException` too.

Comment: Many thanks - it worked, I actually used that method before... The reason I did not think about it was that very similar code was used in Java Script - and it worked, so I thought it is something else